# Как выполнить операцию Any из LINQ для результата асинхронного метода?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, async-await

В общем, есть некоторый массив элементов.

У этих элементов есть асинхронный метод, который возвращает некоторое значение.

Я хочу сделать Any на эту коллекцию, где сравниваю результат этого метода с каким-то значением.

Однако, что-то не соображу, как это сделать.

Пробовал await вставлять в тело, но не работает.

Comment: Что то типа `(await Task.WhenAll(mycollection.Select(x=>x.GetAsync()).ToArray()).Any(x=>x == 10)` ?

Comment: не ясно. Задачи должны выполняться последовательно, но фоном. Или задачи должны выполняться параллельно, если так, то в какой степени параллелизма ?

Answer (score 1):

Не нашел удобного метода, который бы завершился на первом найденном значении. Если это не критично, то проще будет дождаться всех значений.

Из не очень удобного нашел подход, который предложил [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) в вопросе [How to wait tasks with conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824755/how-to-wait-tasks-with-conditions):

- Создать [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.8).
- Для асинхронных методов задать продолжения, в которых будет проверяться значение и устанавливаться завершение `TaskCompletionSource`.
- Дожидаться либо `TaskCompletionSource.Task` либо завершения всех методов.

Получаем что-то вроде такой конструкции:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var elements = new[] {new El(1), new El(7), new El(2)};
        //отдельный таск для отслеживания успешного завершения
        var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        int searchValue = 2;
        var tasks = elements.Select(e => e.Value()
            .ContinueWith(result =>
            {
                //если нашли нужное значение, то завершаем поиск
                if (result.Result == searchValue) completion.TrySetResult(result.Result);
            }));
        //ждем либо успешное завершение, либо завершение всех заданий
        await Task.WhenAny(completion.Task, Task.WhenAll(tasks));
        //нашли или не нашли
        Console.WriteLine($"Found: {completion.Task.IsCompleted}");
        //метод завершится на первом найденном элементе 
    }
}

class El
{
    private readonly int value;

    public El(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public async Task<int> Value()
    {
        await Task.Delay(value * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Получилось громоздко и как всегда с async/await могут быть какие-то подводные камни.

Можно это все обернуть в метод-расширение:

```
public static class AsyncExtensions
{
    public static async Task<bool> AsyncAny<T,U>(this IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T,Task<U>> asyncSelect, Func<U, bool> predicate)
    {
        var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var tasks = data.Select(e => asyncSelect(e)
            .ContinueWith(r =>
            {
                //если нашли нужное значение, то завершаем поиск
                if(predicate(r.Result)) completion.TrySetResult(true);
            }));
        //ждем либо успешное завершение, либо завершение всех заданий
        await Task.WhenAny(completion.Task, Task.WhenAll(tasks));
        return completion.Task.IsCompleted;
    }
}
```

И тогда будет чуть удобнее пользоваться:

```
var asyncAny = await elements.AsyncAny(e=> e.Value(), v => v==2);
```

Comment: Хм... я думал, что есть какой-то штатный механизм...=(

Comment: @iluxa1810 Тоже удивлен. В принципе, вариант, который tym32167 написал в коментах к вопросу (дождаться всех) в худшем случае будет равен по скорости.